# How to prevent contents from going outside its container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm developing a WordPress Responsive theme for my blog. This is the structure of theme. All the content goes in the div "post".

[image]

How do I make all the elements in div "post" take all width from it's container. 
Elements like images, texts are displayed fine but embedded code from YouTube videos, tweets, and facebook looks cropped in the mobile browser.
The current CSS code is:

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
}
.content-area{
 margin: 10px;
 flex: 3;
 order: 1;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.sidebar{
 margin: 10px;
 flex: 1;
 order: 2;
}
.post{
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.post img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If that is all there is to the theme, there needs to be things done. @media-queries for mobile view, for one, where you use all the width of the screen for the post-element, instead of having margins, syrrounding boxes, and sidebar. Also, what do you mean "looks cropped" - you add the elements and style them width 100% width, and that should do it (don't set a height, only a width, the height will stretch/shrink as needed).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. YouTube embeds and Twitter and Facebook widgets are all very different things. It may have nothing to do with your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're embedding `<iframe>` elements when you mention Facebook, Twitter and YouTube. If so, a simple rule like the following could solve your problem:

```
iframe { max-width: 100%!important; }
```

Comment: Throwing `!important` styles at an unclear problem is a recipe for a frustrating maintenance experience.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a style for each element inside your block "post". For pictures I think It is ok.

```html
.post img{
  width: 100%;
}

.post iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

.post .other {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you want something more beautiful you need to use media queries, to adapt for most important devices.